# Dividing polynomial $f(x)$ by $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

> $f(x)$ is a polynomial with a degree greater than 3. When $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$, prove remainder is
>   $$\frac{f(a)(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+ \frac{f(b)(x-a)(x-c)}{(b-c)(b-a)} +\frac{f(c)(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-b)(c-a)}$$

**My Try**

I tried this using the conventional method,$$f(x)=Q(x)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)+Ax^2+Bx+C$$

But then I got long answers for coefficients $A$, $B$ & $C$.
Is there a better way to solve this? Can anyone give me a hint to work this?

Comment: what should be the remainder when $f(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)$ ?

Comment: Note $f(x)=Q(x)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)+R(x)$. What can you say on $R(a), R(b), R(c)$ ? The degree of $R$ is less than $2$. So you can use Lagrange interpolation. There is no need to make an explicit calculation of $A$, $B$, $C$.

Comment: Note that the question doesn't ask you to *derive* that expression for the remainder. Rather it only asks to prove that it *equals* the remainder, which is very easy - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$f(x)=Q(x)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)+Ax^2+Bx+C$$
as you mentioned. Now note that 
$$f(a)=Aa^2+Ba+C\\
f(b)=Ab^2+Bb+C\\
f(c)=Ac^2+Bc+C$$
Now it is easy to solve this system of equations for $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $$f(a)=Aa^2+Ba+C,$$
$$f(b)=Ab^2+Bb+C$$ and $$f(c)=Ac^2+Bc+C.$$
Now, work with the given remainder (it's also a polynomial of the second degree).

Answer (score 0):

Call the purported remainder $\,r(x).$ $\,f(x)-r(x)$ has roots $\,x = a,b,c\,$ so by the [Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242)  $\,f(x)-r(x) = (x\!-\!a)(x\!-\!b)(x\!-\!c) q(x),\,$  so $\deg r < 3\,$ $\Rightarrow\ r(x) =$ remainder by [its *uniqueness*.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/869940/242)

Comment: e.g.  $\ r(a) = f(a)\dfrac{(a\!-\!b)(a\!-\!c)}{(a\!-\!b)(a\!-\!c)} = f(a).\ $ So $\,r(b) = f(b),\ \,r(c) = f(c)\ $ similarly (or by symmetry).